# How to use txt files in C++Builder?

Tags: c++, object, c++builder

I work in C++Builder 6. I have a `file.txt` with 5 words, I would like to be able to save all these words in an `AnsiString`, then change something in them and save it again in `file.txt`. Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Does this help? http://bcbjournal.org/articles/vol2/9803/File_I_O.htm

Answer (score 3):

C++Builder 6 did not offer much in the way of structured file I/O.  Modern versions of C++Builder provide more options.

In BCB6, the simplest solution would be to use the `TStringList` class in `<Classes.hpp>`, with its `LoadFromFile()` and `SaveToFile()` methods, and its `Text` or `Strings[]` properties.

Alternatively, you can use the standard C++ `std::(i|o)fstream` classes in `<fstream>`.  An `AnsiString` can be used with the `<<` and `>>` operators of the standard C++ streams by defining `VCL_IOSTREAM` in your project's Conditionals list.